# Keyword local completion doesn't work with loaded buffers in Vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When I want to autocomplete with <kbd>CTRL-N</kbd> from other buffers, vim doesnt find any matches. I have no idea how to find out what's the problem. My `complete` settings are the default: `complete=.,w,b,u,t,i`.
It only works for the active buffer. I even tried to `:set complete+=U` but no success... How could I track this down ?
My vim version is MacVim (7.3, snapshot 61).

Comment: How many loaded buffers do you have when you do `:ls`? Are they closed/hidden or visible in a split? Do you have `set hidden` in your .vimrc (what does `:set hidden?` return?)?

Comment: I have less then 10, some are hidden, some not, they are not visible, but when visible, it doesn't work either ! I have `set hidden`, so its always on.

Comment: That. Is. Strange. Your setup seems to be perfectly normal. I have the exact same version of MacVim as you with `set hidden` and an untouched `complete` and `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` work fine. Would you mind posting your .vimrc and possibly a list of ftplugins you might use?

Comment: here is my vimrc: http://pastie.org/2608862
I have php.vim, html_snip_helper.vim, vo_base.vim (vimoutliner), pentadactyl.vim, and phpcomplete.vim. Why do ftplugins matter ?

Comment: Plugins/ftplugins may matter because some may overwrite default commands/shortcuts. You could type `:map` to obtain a list of custom shortcuts defined by you, your plugins and the fine folks behind MacVim; see if `<C-n>` is there. You could also look at your plugins. Other than that I don't know: omni-completion is a core feature of Vim and as such is super-reliable. I suggest you ask your question on the Vim mailing list and on the Vim user group. One more question: do other kinds of omni-completion (`<C-x><C-o>` for example) work?

Comment: yes, everything works, even `<C-n><` but only find matches on local buffer...
strange that I have a plugin called 'autocomplpop' and when I enable, it auto find matches from other buffers, as the built-in <C-n> should do...
Hmm, I checked now, and when I disable every plugin with hidden off, it works as expected... So I guess I should track down which plugin is responsible for this mess :D
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey! I find it ! `Supertab` plugin was responsible for this ! :D maybe it remap the `<C-n>` I don't know, but I removed it ! Thanks !

Comment: Hum, if you already have AutoComplPop (which I use) working why do you use `<C-n>` at all? Or even Supertab? ACP already invokes `<C-n>` (and `<C-x><C-o>` & co.) for you automatically, there is no need for calling omni-completion manually. Anyway nice that your problem is solved.

Comment: Sometimes, its annoying so I turn it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Supertab plugin was responsible for the annoyance. (See the comments above)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was [sparkup](http://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup) ftplugin.

Had to add `let g:sparkupNextMapping = '<c-g>n'` (or whatever key you like) to my .vimrc before I load the bundle.